# When debugging a servlet in Eclipse how do I pass my test URL (the request)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, servlets, jboss, m2eclipse

I am new to servlets and I am trying to debug one in Eclipse (Helios Service Release 2).  I started with a Maven project and imported it to Eclipse, using the m2Eclipse plugin.  I am using the Debug As -> Debug on Server option with JBoss 4.0 as my server.  I can set a breakpoint and step through the code, until I need a domain name.  I have not passed the servlet a URL, and it's not finding one.  I have searched in Eclipse for a place to set the URL (perhaps as a parameter?) but I haven't found anywhere for that.  The server is using localhost as host name and 8080 for the port.  Am I supposed to refresh my browser, which is pointing to a test URL (http://localhost:8080/?site=www.testsite.com), at some point in the debugging process?  Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this conundrum.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Are you looking for the domain from the `Request` object, user input, a constant, something else?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer, Aaron, it's one of the handicaps of being a newbie.  Thanks for taking the time to read my question and respond.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not being clearer.  I think I figured it out.  What I was looking for was somewhere to enter my URL request and I found it.  After I started my debug session in Eclipse, I changed the perspective to Web Development and that gave me a browser window in the IDE for entering my URL.  I then went back to the Debug perspective and the browser window stayed. So I could set my breakpoints and step through the code.  I control the servlet through that browser window in Eclipse. There are still a few things that are a little murky about the whole process, but I think I can do this at will now.  I hope this helps any other newbies in the same position.

Comment: it is still unclear what the problem was.. but good you solved it

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I feel pretty stupid.  I didn't need to enter the URL in Eclipse; I can use any browser and go back and forth between the debug session in Eclipse and the browser.  Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.